# Getting CSV saving in the document folder

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

I know this question probably appeared million times, but I cannot get my code to work.

I want to upload csv to a folder, so I can make further operations on it.

I think the problem might be in my HTML code, but not sure where.
Folder I want to save it to is documents/, I did not add it to settings.py but I saw other people were not adding it there either.

My code is as per below:
Main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from mainsite import views as main

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', main.index, name= 'index'),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    path('explanation/', include('modelexpl.urls')),
    path('uploads/', main.model_form_upload, name='model_form_upload')


]
```

App urls.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path
from mainsite import views
# Create your views here.

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

App's models.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank= True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

App's views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mainsite.models import Document
from mainsite.forms import DocumentForm

# Create your views here.

def index (request):
    placeholder = {'test' : 'test'}
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mainsite/index.html', { 'documents': documents })


def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
            print("uploaded")

    else:
        form = Upload()
        print("trying")

    return render(request, 'mainsite/index.html', {'form' : form})
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Make sure your csv doesn't exceed 250mb!</label>
    <br>


    <form action = "{% url 'index' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

  </div>
</form>
{% for obj in documents %}
  <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ obj.document.url }}">{{ obj.document }}</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Appreciate any help, I spent on it very long time and am really lost!

Also, I am planning to use this saved csv to having ML models on, then return another csv back after processing, you think that'd be the most efficient way to do that in terms of speed and use of Django? (I'm data scientist/statistician, that is my side hobby project)

Comment: just to add, when I click submit the page just refreshes extended with what i beleive is csrf token, no indication of file being saved .

Comment: For user uploaded files, you must set your media settings in settings.py. See the docs for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/

Comment: @wjh18 I have added MEDIA_URL = '/documents/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'documents')
 but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form of your HTML you have action set to a wrong view to process the form once submitted.

you have:

```
<form action = "{% url 'index' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Change it to:

```
<form action = "{% url 'model_form_upload' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but unfortunately this have not fixed the issue :(

Comment: print forms.errors before you save the form, there could be errors in your form

Comment: I have rewritten the entire code, there was an error in html above , when i didnt put '/' ... literally 6 hours spent on such simple error!

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i accepted your answer :)

Comment: You are welcome, that is how beautiful programming is,